# How to check CSS background images are loaded using htmlunit?

Tags: java, htmlunit, web-crawler

I have created small crawler using htmlunit which checks for LINK , Anchor, IMG , SCRIPT tags And verifies that all src/links/files are not broken.

But how can I get links to the images used in css background property? using htmlunit..